# How to ignore one unity package in source control

Tags: unity, version-control, git

I've just installed the Unity [quick search](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.quicksearch@2.0/manual/index.html) package. This is an editor extension which each developer should choose if they want installed or not. My problem is that because this was added as a package it also made changes to my project which would end-up in our repository.

The changes are:

```
Project root/
|── Assets/
|   |── Assets.index
|   └── Assets.index.meta
|── Packages/
|   |── manifest.json
|   └── packages-lock.json
|── UserSettings/
    └── QuickSearch.settings
```

Questions:

1. Should this files be added to source control?
2. How can I ignore the changes in `manifest.json` and `packages-lock.json` without filters?

Comment: Any specific reason to not add "quick search" in your repository?

Comment: @DigvijaysinhGohil because it's personal decision whether to use it or not. It's the same as forcing a team member to use the same shortcuts as me. And also because the application can work at runtime and can also be compiled without that package istanlled.

Comment: Only solution I can think of right now is either don't upload your manifest entirely or create another branch and at merge time stash your menifest, in both cases when you pull you have to re-add your package again. This is not the solution but until you find one this might help.